# Using Laravel Sanctum Returns FATAL:SASL Authentication Error

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to figure out why Sanctum gives off this error when I try to login my system.

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server at "10.1.80.217", port 5000 failed: FATAL: SASL authentication failed
```

These are the files mentioned in the Laravel Sanctum Documentation which I've already checked but I still don't know what is causing this error. I'll also show the my login page and the related files to it. (I'm using Vue 3 as my frontend.)

Any help is appreciated.

Laravel 9.44.0

PHP 8.22

Vue 3

SignIn.vue (submit login)

```
 onSubmit() {
        this.errors = {};
        this.loading = true;
        this.$store.dispatch('sanctum/signIn', this.params())
            .then(() => {
                this.$router.replace({ path: "/" });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.throwColor("input", "input.username", "text-amber");
                this.throwColor("input", "input.password", "text-amber");
                this.errors = this.signInErrors(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
    },
```

action.js

```
export function signIn(context, data) {
    return api.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
        .then(() => {
            return api.post('sanctum/signin', {
                'username': data.username,
                'password': data.password
            })
                .then(user => {
                    let userArray = Object.values(user.data);
                    let key = userArray.join('|');
                    user.data['key'] = window.btoa(key);

                    return api.get('/api/domain/core/administration/security/users/' + user.data.id + '/authorizations', {
                        // params: { id: user.data.id },
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        }
                    })
                        .then((authorizations) => {
                            return context.dispatch('credentials', {
                                user: user.data,
                                role: authorizations.data[0],
                                permission: authorizations.data[1]
                            })
                                .then(() => { return [user, authorizations]; });
                        })
                });
        })
}
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=****
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=****
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

CHECK_BROWSER=false

DB_CONNECTION=forgestampede
DB_HOST=10.1.80.217
DB_PORT=5000
DB_PORT_READ=5001
DB_DATABASE=forgestampede
DB_USERNAME=****
DB_PASSWORD=****

BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
CACHE_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVERFILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_EXPIRE_ON_CLOSE=true
SESSION_ENCRYPT=true
SESSION_DOMAIN=****
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true
SESSION_SAME_SITE=strict

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=****

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=10.1.80.217
REDIS_PASSWORD=****
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=****
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=****
MAIL_PASSWORD=****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=****
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

SFTP_HOST=10.1.80.217
SFTP_USERNAME=****
SFTP_PASSWORD=****
SFTP_PORT=2229
SFTP_ROOT=/uploads

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=****
PUSHER_APP_KEY=****
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=****
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
PUSHER_HOST=10.1.80.217

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Database.php

```
'forgestampede' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'read' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
                    'port' => env('DB_PORT_READ'),
                ],
                // [
                //     'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
                //     'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
                // ]
            ],
            'write' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('DB_HOST'),
                    'port' => env('DB_PORT'),
                ]
            ],
            'sticky' => true,
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'search_path' => 'core',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

Sanctum.php

```
<?php

use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Stateful Domains
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Requests from the following domains / hosts will receive stateful API
    | authentication cookies. Typically, these should include your local
    | and production domains which access your API via a frontend SPA.
    |
    */

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array contains the authentication guards that will be checked when
    | Sanctum is trying to authenticate a request. If none of these guards
    | are able to authenticate the request, Sanctum will use the bearer
    | token that's present on an incoming request for authentication.
    |
    */

    'guard' => ['web'],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Expiration Minutes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value controls the number of minutes until an issued token will be
    | considered expired. If this value is null, personal access tokens do
    | not expire. This won't tweak the lifetime of first-party sessions.
    |
    */

    'expiration' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sanctum Middleware
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When authenticating your first-party SPA with Sanctum you may need to
    | customize some of the middleware Sanctum uses while processing the
    | request. You may change the middleware listed below as required.
    |
    */

    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array<string, array<int, class-string|string>>
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array<string, class-string|string>
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'validate.browser' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckBrowser::class,
        'rbac' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPermission::class,
    ];
}
```

cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,

];
```

bootstrap.js

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
//     forceTLS: true
// });
```

session.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Session Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default session "driver" that will be used on
    | requests. By default, we will use the lightweight native driver but
    | you may specify any of the other wonderful drivers provided here.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "cookie", "database", "apc",
    |            "memcached", "redis", "dynamodb", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => env('SESSION_EXPIRE_ON_CLOSE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Encryption
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to easily specify that all of your session data
    | should be encrypted before it is stored. All encryption will be run
    | automatically by Laravel and you can use the Session like normal.
    |
    */

    'encrypt' => env('SESSION_ENCRYPT'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session File Location
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the native session driver, we need a location where session
    | files may be stored. A default has been set for you but a different
    | location may be specified. This is only needed for file sessions.
    |
    */

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" or "redis" session drivers, you may specify a
    | connection that should be used to manage these sessions. This should
    | correspond to a connection in your database configuration options.
    |
    */

    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Database Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "database" session driver, you may specify the table we
    | should use to manage the sessions. Of course, a sensible default is
    | provided for you; however, you are free to change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'table' => 'sessions',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cache Store
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | While using one of the framework's cache driven session backends you may
    | list a cache store that should be used for these sessions. This value
    | must match with one of the application's configured cache "stores".
    |
    | Affects: "apc", "dynamodb", "memcached", "redis"
    |
    */

    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Sweeping Lottery
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Some session drivers must manually sweep their storage location to get
    | rid of old sessions from storage. Here are the chances that it will
    | happen on a given request. By default, the odds are 2 out of 100.
    |
    */

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the name of the cookie used to identify a session
    | instance by ID. The name specified here will get used every time a
    | new session cookie is created by the framework for every driver.
    |
    */

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The session cookie path determines the path for which the cookie will
    | be regarded as available. Typically, this will be the root path of
    | your application but you are free to change this when necessary.
    |
    */

    'path' => '/',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Cookie Domain
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
    | in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
    | available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
    |
    */

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTPS Only Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By setting this option to true, session cookies will only be sent back
    | to the server if the browser has a HTTPS connection. This will keep
    | the cookie from being sent to you when it can't be done securely.
    |
    */

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | HTTP Access Only
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Setting this value to true will prevent JavaScript from accessing the
    | value of the cookie and the cookie will only be accessible through
    | the HTTP protocol. You are free to modify this option if needed.
    |
    */

    'http_only' => true,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Same-Site Cookies
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines how your cookies behave when cross-site requests
    | take place, and can be used to mitigate CSRF attacks. By default, we
    | will set this value to "lax" since this is a secure default value.
    |
    | Supported: "lax", "strict", "none", null
    |
    */

    'same_site' => env('SESSION_SAME_SITE'),

];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct DB connection information in your .env file. It is probably wrong credentials. Check if everything is correct and case sensitive here :

```
DB_CONNECTION=forgestampede
DB_HOST=10.1.80.217
DB_PORT=5000
DB_PORT_READ=5001
DB_DATABASE=forgestampede
DB_USERNAME=****
DB_PASSWORD=****
```

It also may be related to the wrong Port. Seems like you are using local app with distant database. Make sure you are not trying to access a production Database.

Comment: I used the credentials written in the env file to check the database using pgAdmin so I think that's not the culprit. Wouldn't hurt to double check it though. Thanks for the input.

Comment: How are you using DB_PORT and DB_PORT_READ ? Maybe add your database.php forgestampede connection code ?